# ¿Es posible acceder a una variable en Java haciendo referencia a su nombre?

Tags: java

Tengo la siguiente inquietud para la cual estoy buscando la mejor solución, de ser posible en Java. Aclaro, que la rutina del `for` incluye un error que es justamente el origen de la inquietud.

Declaro unas constantes, por ejemplo:

```
Map<String, Map<Integer, String>> mAlgo = new HashMap();
Map<Integer, String> mPartes = new HashMap();

String[] aPartes = {"top", "left", ...};
String[] aEstados = {"Solido", "Flexible", ...};

String[][] topSolido = {
  {"parte11", "parte12", "parte13"},
  {"parte21", "parte22", "parte23"},
  ...
};
String[][] topFlexible = {
  {"parte11", "parte12", "parte13"},
  {"parte21", "parte22", "parte23"},
  ...
};

String[][] leftSolido = {
  {"parte11", "parte12", "parte13"},
  {"parte21", "parte22", "parte23"},
  ...
};
String[][] leftFlexible = {
  {"parte11", "parte12", "parte13"},
  {"parte21", "parte22", "parte23"},
  ...
};

for (String sParte : aPartes) {
  for (String sEstado : aEstados) {
    String sEnsamble = sParte + sEstado;
    for (int f=0; f<sEnsamble.length; f++) {
      for (int c=0; c<sEnsamble[f].length; c++) {
        mPartes.put(c, sEnsamble[f][c]);
      }
      mAlgo.put(sEnsamble, mPartes);
      mPartes.clear();
    }
  }
}
```

La parte **crucial** del ejercicio es que arroja un obvio error, está cuando se intenta recorrer la variable, como si estuviera fuera la matriz a la que hace referencia su valor. Después de la siguiente asignación:

```
String sEnsamble = sParte + sEstado;
```

Es decir...

```
for (int f=0; f<sEnsamble.length; f++) {
    ...
}
```

Esto en la práctica hace que `sEnsamble` tome los valores `"topSolido"`, `"topFlexible"`, `"leftSolido"`, `"leftFlexible"` sucesivamente, que coinciden con los nombres de cada una de las matrices previamente declaradas.

¿Existe un mecanismo en Java que permita hacer algo semejante a lo propuesto? o ¿Es posible cargar la información del mapa `"mAlgo"` con la estructura propuesta `Map<String, Map<Integer, String>>` como una constante ej: `"M_ALGO"` desde un principio sin tener que realizar esta conversión en un método cualquiera?

Comment: Hola Charlie. Seré yo solamente, pero por mas que leo la pregunta, no entiendo. Ni siquiera sé que pregunta hacer para aclarar la pregunta. No entiendo lo que estás tratando de lograr.

Comment: idem por acá... no logré entender cual es tu problema. Por lo que veo, tienes un sEnsamble como un String, pero lo quieres recorrer como una matriz... Definitivamente no entiendo.

Comment: Parece ser que la pregunta no ha sido comprendida en su totalidad para lo cual hago la siguiente aclaración. Si quisiera pasar la información de las matrices al mapa propuesto, el procedimiento sería algo como:

Comment: Para aclarar la inquietud, imaginen que la cantidad de matrices del ejercicio puede aumentar en el tiempo. Se desea paras dicha información a mapas. Para hacerlo, se debe, 1)declarar por un lado las matrices como constantes y para luego llevarlas a los mapas se debe 2) hacer alusión manualmente a cada una de ellas si se quiere copiar su información en los mapas respectivos. El ejercicio obvia la segunda parte (Ej: pasarAMapa(topSolido), luego: pasarAMapa(topFlexible), luego: pasarAMapa(leftSolido), etc, etc, etc.). Se busca evitar esto último. Si persisten dudas al respecto, estaré atento.

Answer (score 4):

Sí, pero sólo para miembros de una clase. Y la verdad, **a no ser que sepás muy bien qué estás haciendo y PORQUÉ LO HACES ASÍ**, las posibilidades de que no te interese usar esta solución son considerables.

El paquete `java.lang.reflect` incluye clases para analizar y tratar las propias clases de Java. Puedes instanciar una clase pasándo el nombre de la clase como un String, acceder a un método o propiedad de la clase de la misma manera, etc.

Por ejemplo, para crear una instancia de una clase BigDecimal:

```
Class claseBD = Class.forName("java.math.BigDecimal");
Constructor constructor = claseBd.getConstructor(String.class); // Referencia al constructor que acepta un String.
BigDecimal bd = (BigDecimal) constructor.newInstance("342348948247897980");
```

De forma similar, puedes obtener los métodos de una instancia y ejecutarlos.

```
Method metodoSetScale = claseBd.getMethod("setScale", Integer.type);
metodoSetScale.invoke(bd, 4); // Igual que hacer bd.setScale(4);
```

y obtener los atributos con `getField`.

¿Por qué desaconsejo que se use? Pues es muy potente, y es muy tentador empezar a hacer inventos de este tipo, pero a menos que se estructuren muy bien, acabas complicando el código mucho y teniendo errores en tiempo de ejecución que habrías descubierto con compilación.

Si tienes experiencia como para montar un framework tipo CDI o JSF con una funcionalidad cerrada y bien definida son muy útiles, pero si no trátalos con respeto. Si no, estoy seguro que no soy el único que ha heredado un proyecto para encontrarse con multitud de errores porque alguien ideó una forma "fácil" de generar SQL a partir de los datos de reflection y otras genialidades.

Para tu caso, si quieres seguir ese camino de combinar nombres, es mucho más sencillo hacer un `Map<String, String[][]>` y usar lo que en tu ejemplo eran "nombres de variables" como claves.

Comment: Tu respuesta me ayudó a entender la pregunta :)

Comment: También se pueden leer variable desde fuera de la clase si esas variables son visibles desde donde se use Reflection. También es interesante la diferencia entre `getField()` que son todos los campos (heredados también) y `getDeclaredField()` que son sólo los declarados en esa clase directamente.

Comment: Muchas gracias. Ahondaré en el tema. Busco entre otras, aunque suene en un principio confuso, realizar llamadas del tipo: metodo(parteVerde); siendo "parteVerde" una variable declarada en cualquier lugar y sea a su vez, la suma de dos textos: "parte" y "Verde" que resultan de algún proceso. Esto evitaría cosas del tipo: case "caso1": metodo(parteVerde); ...  case "caso2": metodo(parteAzul); y así un largo etc. que se agregan cada vez que se declaran constantes, obligando a su vez a actualizar el swicth o switchs donde se requieran provocando errores por posibles omisiones. Gracias nuevamente.